# I deleted the update file for iOS 9.3. Is it possible to reinstall it?

Tags: iphone, ios

I was having trouble installing the new iOS 9.3 on my iPhone 5 and I got the advice that I should delete the update file and try to reinstall it. The problem is now that I have deleted the file I can't find the update file for iOS 9.3 again. I have restarted the phone but it didn't help, it says I have the latest update (9.2.1). Is it possible to install iOS 9.3 now?

Update: I got the new update today randomly. The installation of 9.3 went successfull.

Comment: Try it from a computer on iTunes. Not the first report of that this week.

Comment: I have tried that aswell. Itunes says i have the latest update which is 9.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has pulled the iOS 9.3 update for some (older) devices because of a bug that could prevent using your device. Apple is not signing iOS 9.3 for your iPhone (5s and older), so **it is not possible to update by official means at this time**. According to the link below, 9.3 could potentially brick an older phone under certain conditions.

Source: http://9to5mac.com/2016/03/24/bricked-iphone-5s-5-ipad-2-ios-9-3-fix/

Comment: I don't remember having to enter the Apple ID and password used to originally set up the device when i tried to download it so i guess not. It just said something about the update couldn't be installed because i "lost my internet connection" when i know for a fact i there was nothing wrong with my internet connection. Just weird.

Comment: What device are you using? What iPhone?

Comment: I have the Iphone 5

Answer (score -1):

Several sites host the ipsw file for 9.3.  That's similar to a zip file but it's for ios.  You can do a simple google search for sites but you need to be careful and make sure the file hasn't been messed with.  I often go to [OSXDaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2016/03/21/ios-9-3-update-download-ipsw/) to get my files.  From there you can download the 9.3 file and install it following the instructions. This will update your iPhone to 9.3.

Comment: Golden rule: Don't use any site that hosts it themselves. use one that merely links to the Apple hosted version. OSXDaily is one of the latter & quite safe - example link for the 6s... http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS9.3/031-20814-20160321-50FF38D4-EAA8-11E5-AAA8-C479BD379832/iPhone8,1_9.3_13E234_Restore.ipsw

Comment: http://ipsw.me is the best site for IPSWs.